# The number of triangles with each side having integral length...

Tags: permutations

The number of triangles with each side having integral length and the longest side is of 11 units is:-?   MY ATTEMPT:-   I applied following constraints: $12 \leq {a+b} \leq 22$ $a,b \geq 1$ I made different cases that a+b =12, a+b=13 and so on. My answer came was 160 but it is not the correct one.

Comment: Yah. That means sum of two sides that is a+b should be greater than or equal to 12. Because third side is 11 and all sides are integral.

Comment: @Ruchit Vithani: Check your counts. Note that $(a,b)=(1,11)$ gives the same triangle as $(a,b) = (11,1)$, so for the purposes of the count, you can assume $a \le b$.

Comment: Why are you specifying that a+b <= 22?  That is not a condition.  The only condition is that $a \le 11; b \le 11$.  You can not, for instance $a = 13$ and $b =2$ but only because you are told the longest side is $11$ so $a \le 11$.  Other wise there would be no limit to the sides and there are none to the sum of the sides at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditions are not quite correct.  There is no stipulation on what $a + b$ is the only stipulation is that $11$ is the longest sides.

We need $a \le b \le 11$ so we don't count multiple instances the same and so that the maximum side(s) is $11$.

We need $a + b > 11$ or $a + b \ge 12$ to satisfy the (non-trivial) triangle inequality.

So the answer is $\sum\limits_{a=1}^{11}\sum\limits_{b=\max(a,12-a)}^{11}1$

$= \sum\limits_{a=1}^{11}[12- \max(a,12-a)]$

$= \sum\limits_{a=1}^{11}\min(12-a, a)$

$= 1 + 2 + 3 + 4+ 5 + 6 +5 + 4 + 3+2+1 = 21 + 15 = 36$.

I.E. $(a,b) = $

$(1,11)$

$(2,10)..(2, 11)$

$(3,9)....(3,11)$.

.....

$(5,7)....(5,11)$.

$(6,6)....(6,11)$.

$(7,7)....(7,11)$.

......

$(10,11)...(11,11)$

$(11,11)$

Answer (score 0):

Forget the previous answer
Let us assume $a\geq b$ so if $a=11$ the b has 11 (1-11) possibilities
if $a=10$ b has 9 possibilites (2-10). $a=9$ we have 7 possibilities(3-9)... and so on
so the total is: 11+9+7...1=**36** (sum of first n odd numbers in n^2)

Comment: Correct answer is 36.

Comment: ok i will check if I made a mistake

Comment: See the problem is that I would have counted triangle such as (10,2,11) and (2,10,11) as different. If you want them as same I will have to subtract.

Comment: And yah! If we go with this method the sum of coefficients from 12-22 are like this 11+12+....+21. And another mistake in this one is (a,b) = (8,9) and (a,b) =(9,8) will give same triangle while they are counted different in this method.

Comment: No u cant calculate the coeeficients of 12 to 22 like that because there is a $(1-x^{11})^2$ term when that expand out you will have to subtract terms and you will get the same answer

Comment: i am sorry for confusing you there is a very simple solution

Comment: What's that tell me

Comment: check the soultion